# Oracle foreign key error invalid identifier

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, oracle10g, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
Name varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
R_date date NOT NULL,
D_address varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
Email_id varchar2(30) NOT NULL,
No_of_cars int NOT NULL,
Contact_no varchar2(15) NOT NULL,
Price int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FK_CarBooking FOREIGN KEY (C_ID)
REFERENCES Car(C_ID)
);
```

CONSTRAINT FK_CarBooking FOREIGN KEY (C_ID)

```
    ERROR at line 10:
ORA-00904: "C_ID": invalid identifier
```

In Car table C_ID is primary key. I don't understand why it's saying invalid identifier.

Comment: There is no column `c_id` in the `booking` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CONSTRAINT FK_CarBooking FOREIGN KEY (C_ID)
REFERENCES Car(C_ID)
```

The first C_ID must exist within the table **Booking** and the second in the **Car** table.

In order to solve this problem, add a field named C_ID inside the Booking table.